# Use cases for offline board

Tags: agile, tools

We as a team were using Offline Board to hold our tickets from tracking system (Jira in our case) for quite some time.
Now we are finding that the tickets on the board do not work very well, but the board itself became a place where we gather for a standup.

At the moment we are investigating how to put something like calendar on it, but I believe there are other great usages for it.

So I'm curious what could be other use cases for an offline board?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Scrum I have seen physical task boards used for the following:

- Holidays and planned absences (can be as simple as post-its with names and dates)
- Burn-down or burn-up charts (updated daily)
- Team's definition of done
- Team's definition of ready
- Product roadmap (giving the team a longer-term vision for the product)

Also, the task board doesn't need to be only focused towards the team. You can use it as an *information radiator* showing others in your organisation what the team is up to. Perhaps showing wire frames or screen shots.

Comment: So we put there the following information: Upcoming Events (such as releases including biggest features, important meetings, etc.), Vacations/Home Office to track team members availability. Another thing on the board is QA news, which is basically high-level testing plan.

Answer (score 0):

We use one of the offline boards to highlight the software components we are working on four other teams to identify dependencies. One is used for concepting and the last is used for project portfolio.